# inputs y checkbox selecion insercion

Tags: php, mysqli

[image: Vista de la plantilla de oobras]Saludos tengo un inconveniente estoy tratando de habilitar Inputs a medida que seleccione checkbox, el problema incurre en que son checkbox mostrados por un `while` el cual llega desde la base de datos. Mas abajo muestro el código.

```
<div class="campo clearfix">
      <label for="herram" id="herra">Selecionar herramientas:</label><br/>
        <?php
          try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM herramienta";
            $res_herram = $conn->query($sql);
            $total_h = $res_herram->num_rows;
            $i = 0;
            while ($herram = $res_herram->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo '<div class="contenido_dia">';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" id='"checkh" . $herram['id_herra'] . ' name="herram[]"  value=' . $herram['id_herra'] . '> ' . $herram['nom_herra'] . " " ;
            echo '<input type="number" min="0" max="5" disabled="disabled" id='"canth". $herram['id_herra'] . ' size="1" name="herram_cant[]" placeholder="0">' . '<br/>';
            echo '</div>';
            $i++;
            }
          } catch (Exception $error) {
            echo "Error:" . $error->getMessage();
          }
        ?>
    </div>
```

estaba intentado con este javascript pero creo que esta va muy mal

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
$("#checkh" + i).change(function(){
var comentario = $( '#canth' +i, $(this).parents ('div'));
if( $(this.checked)){
  comentario.removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
  comentario.attr('disabled', true);
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de crear un disparador para cada checkbox con su id, es mejor crear uno para todos los checkbox contenidos dentro del `div.campo` sin tener en cuenta cuantos hay ni la id que tiene cada uno.

Cuando se ejecuta el disparador solo tienes que seleccionar el siguiente input de tipo numero y activarlo o desactivarlo según necesites.

Para activar i desactivar inputs con jQuery se recomienda usar el método `.prop()`.

Javascript:

```
$('div.campo').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {

  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).next('input[type=number]').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $(this).next('input[type=number]').prop('disabled', true);
  }

});
```

Comment: excelente amigo, diste en el clavo, salvo que cambie el `('div.campo')` por el siguiente DIV `('div.contenido_dia')` y va de lo mejor. aprendiendo un poco mas, esto es para mi proyecto de graduacion